# PTIJ: Was Mordechai's greeting "priorities" backwards?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Megillah says about Mordechai (10:3):

> דורש טוב לעמו ודובר שלום לכל זרעו
>
> He inquires about the good (welfare) of his people and says 'Hello' to
> his children.

Maybe I'm old-fashioned. I would think that a father should first be concerned about the welfare of his own children before the welfare of his fellowmen. And, I would also think that he should give his children a much bigger greeting and a huge hug and have a longer conversation when he sees his children. Much more than just a passing "Hello".

Did Mordechai's promotion as vice minister make him so pompous that he forgot his priorities?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Did he even have children?